# systemctl restart logrotate throws error "Failed to restart logrotate.service: Unit not found."

Tags: linux, logging, redhat, rsyslog, logrotate

I'm trying to make changes to logrotate.conf just to be sure before making changes to md_logging.c
I'm not able to check the functionality through

`systemctl restart logrotate`

`Failed to restart logrotate.service: Unit not found.`

I also tried logrotate.conf with the following command :

`systemctl restart logrotate.conf`

`Failed to restart logrotate.conf.service: Unit not found.`

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: `logrotate` isn't a daemonized service, it's an executable that gets executed at specific moments in time, typically by cron. There is no 'daemon' to speak of or restart. Whatever your config files are at the moment of execution is what will be considered by `logrotate` upon execution.

Answer (score 0):

If the logrotate package is installed, and you are still having the problems, you might be able to get the latest status by:

`cat /var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status`